# Combining these queries? (Same taxonomy term + same category as post)

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms

I´m not to good at coding so I could use some help with this!
I have a single page which below the post shows more posts from the same category. Then I have another single page which in a similare fashion shows more posts from the same taxonomy term as the current post.

I would like to combine this to show posts from the same category and taxonomy term as the current post.

Code for "same taxonomy term": http://pastebin.com/ebpbzfNi
Code for "same category" : http://pastebin.com/kB0n49Bd

If someone would help me with this I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `'category__in' => $category_id_array` argument from your second query inside your first query.

If this doesn't work, make a tax_query, with both `kund` and `post_category` taxonomies